# Motherboard with no POST code beeps

Tags: cpu, motherboard, power-supply

I was helping my son put together a new computer and we've run across a weird problem.
We started with an [MSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro-Star_International#Products) motherboard, [Core i7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Core#Core_i7) processor, generic case, 8 GB ballistic DDR3, and power supply. The motherboard(s) in question have built-in video. I have plugged in the case-speaker to the correct place on the motherboard.

After putting the pieces together and turning it on, I got power to the fans and nothing else - no [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test) codes, no signal on the video.

So, I replaced the power supply (different brand). 
So, I replaced the motherboard ([ASRock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASRock#History) this time). Same result (with both power supplies in the new board). 
So, I replaced the CPU. Same result (with both power supplies and both motherboards).

I have tried all combinations of the above with and without/RAM trying to just get a POST beep, but no luck. I'm running out of parts to replace. My only thought is that the RAM is bad or in the wrong slots (though I've tried more), but I'd think I'd get some sort of POST code by booting without RAM.

Here are the two motherboards

1. ASRock Z87 Pro 4
2. MSI Z87 G41

The processor is an Intel i7-4770K (I tried two different ones - same model).

Comment: Are you using all the PSU connectors?  There should be the big standard one, and one for the GPU, and possibly a third - I am not familiar with the board.

Comment: I assume after you turn it on, the fans remain on / LED's on the case or motherboard (if there are any) remain on?

Comment: ya, i think my connectors are good. I have the big ones and the two little ones. don't see a separate one for the gpu on the motherboard.

Comment: front case lights work fine. i've experimented with plugging in the hard disk, etc. no hard disk light ever seems to go on, though.

Comment: The speaker part of the case or a 1-channel speaker on a wire?

Comment: a one channel speaker on a wire. i even tried 2 speakers to be sure:)

Comment: Could you post the models of the motherboards and processors you tried, please?

Comment: i'll post the brands and models, have to do it later today though.

Comment: Motherboard and processor info added.

Comment: If the only thing in common is the processor, the problem is probably the processor.

Comment: ya, but i did try two different (same model) processors. i have two processor, 2 motherboards, and 2 power supplies. have tried all combinations of each.

Comment: So, the only thing in common now is the case? Can you inspect it for anything which could be contacting the motherboard where it shouldn't? It will be untidy, but can you assemble it on a non-conductive, non-staticy surface with the components outside the case? - you'll still need to be able to connect the case's power switch to the motherboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, as unlikely as it seemed to me, getting a new case fixed the problem. I am not sure if the issue was the mount points, the switch, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's likely that some of the PSU plugs weren't connected.

It's less likely, but if the board was shorting against the case, that could have been part of your problem.

It is always a good idea to make sure that the board is well elevated by standoffs.

They give an example here at about 1:40 in the video.

http://www.gcflearnfree.org/macosxmavericks/6

Comment: The link is broken: *"Error: 404. Much like the Loch Ness Monster, the page you requested does not exist."*